# io.connect: io is not defined but socket.io is loaded

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I have built a node.js server that provides a client.html page with a list of messages from a mysql db. I can't make it work using an ajax call.
The client.html page is this:

```
        <time></time>
        <div id="container">Loading ...</div>
        <script src="http://oclock.dyndns.org:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>

        // create a new websocket
        var socket = io.connect('http://oclock.dyndns.org:8000');
        // on message received we print all the data inside the #container div
        socket.on('notification', function (data) {
        var msgs = '<div>';
        $.each(data.flashmsgs,function(index,flashmsg){
            msgs += "<b>Messaggio inviato da " + flashmsg.created_by + "</b><br>";
            msgs += flashmsg.testo;
        });
        msgs += '</div>';
        $('#container').html(msgs);

        $('time').html('Last Update:' + data.time);
      });
    </script>
```

and the code for the ajax call is the following:

```
    (function nodeLoader(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "client.html",
            method: "get",
            data: {hk: hk },
            success: function(data){
                $('#messaggi').html(data);
            }
        });
    })();
```

The socket.io code is loaded but I get an error on io.connect: io is not defined. Same issue if i change the url from client.html to http://oclock.dyndns.org:8000 (the url of the node.js server that is listening for requests).
Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:
server.js

```
var hwkey;
var app = require('http').createServer(handler),
  io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
  url = require('url'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  mysql = require('mysql'),
  connectionsArray = [],
  connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'flipper',
    database: 'oclock',
    port: 3306
  }),
  POLLING_INTERVAL = 3000,
  pollingTimer;

// If there is an error connecting to the database
connection.connect(function(err) {
  // connected! (unless `err` is set)
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});

// creating the server ( localhost:8000 )
app.listen(8000);


function handler(req, res) {
    var origin = (req.headers.origin || "*");
    if (req.method.toUpperCase() === "OPTIONS"){
      res.writeHead(
          "204",
          "No Content",
          {
              "access-control-allow-origin": origin,
              "access-control-allow-methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
              "access-control-allow-headers": "content-type, accept",
              "access-control-max-age": 10, // Seconds.
              "content-length": 0
          }
      );
      return( res.end() );
    }

    console.log("INCOMING REQUEST: "+req.method+" "+req.url);
    req.parsed_url = url.parse(req.url, true);
    var getp = req.parsed_url.query;
    hwkey = getp.hk;

    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/client.html', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading client.html');
    }
    res.writeHead(
                  200,
                    {
                        "access-control-allow-origin": origin,
                        "content-length": data.length
                    }
                  );
    res.end(data);
  });
}


function pollingLoop(){
  // Doing the database query
  var query = connection.query('SELECT id, testo, created_by FROM flashmsgs WHERE hwk="'+hwkey+'" AND letto="0"'),
  //var query = connection.query('SELECT max(id), testo, created_by FROM flashmsgs'),
    flashmsgs = []; // this array will contain the result of our db query

  // setting the query listeners
  query
    .on('error', function(err) {
      // Handle error, and 'end' event will be emitted after this as well
      console.log(err);
      updateSockets(err);
    })
    .on('result', function(flashmsg) {
      // it fills our array looping on each user row inside the db
      flashmsgs.push(flashmsg);
    })
    .on('end', function() {
      // loop on itself only if there are sockets still connected
      if (connectionsArray.length) {

        pollingTimer = setTimeout(pollingLoop, POLLING_INTERVAL);

        updateSockets({
          flashmsgs: flashmsgs
        });
      } else {

        console.log('The server timer was stopped because there are no more socket connections on the app')

      }
    });
};


// creating a new websocket to keep the content updated without any AJAX request
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

  console.log('Number of connections:' + connectionsArray.length);
  // starting the loop only if at least there is one user connected
  if (!connectionsArray.length) {
    pollingLoop();
  }

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    var socketIndex = connectionsArray.indexOf(socket);
    console.log('socketID = %s got disconnected', socketIndex);
    if (~socketIndex) {
      connectionsArray.splice(socketIndex, 1);
    }
  });

  console.log('A new socket is connected!');
  connectionsArray.push(socket);

});

var updateSockets = function(data) {
  // adding the time of the last update
  data.time = new Date();
  console.log('Pushing new data to the clients connected ( connections amount = %s ) - %s', connectionsArray.length , data.time);
  console.log(hwkey);
  // sending new data to all the sockets connected
  connectionsArray.forEach(function(tmpSocket) {
    tmpSocket.volatile.emit('notification', data);
  });
};

console.log('Please use your browser to navigate to http://localhost:8000');
```

Comment: Please also post the server socket.io code.

Comment: When I navigate to your app http://oclock.dyndns.org:8000/client.html, it appears to be working does it not? I can see in Chrome dev tools that socket.io is connected and refreshing the timestamp.

Comment: it does. Now I am trying to integrate the result in the main application index page. The app is running on port 80. Try http://oclock.dyndns.org/?hk=a1b2c3d4e5f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I misunderstood at first. I just investigated your live app and it appears your ajax call is pulling down an entire html document.

[image]

If you're loading markup via ajax and then inserting into the existing page, you don't want a full HTML document. Just send down the body content.

Also, the socket.io script reference should ideally be on the parent page, not the page loaded via ajax.

Comment: I am using <script src="http://oclock.dyndns.org:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> because from a page that is on port 80 I am requesting a resource that is on 8000 and socket.io.js is loaded (as I see from firebug)

Comment: the point is that the socket code is loaded but not used. It works if I use the url in the ajax passing it in a new window in the browser

Comment: See my edited answer. You don't want to stick a full HTML document into an existing HTML document. Your endpoint on the server should return an HTML snippet that can be inserted into the existing DOM. You only want that markup to be a full document if you're pointing your browser directly at it for a full page load. Not sure yet if it will fix the `io` reference, but I wouldn't be surprised if sticking a full HTML document into the existing page is causing something wonky.

Comment: Yes, the client.html code is to be "cleaned"of all unnecessary items. Can you explain me please what do you mean with "the socket.io script reference should ideally be on the parent page, not the page loaded via ajax" Thanks very much for your help :)

Comment: Those `<script>` tags that come down with the document loaded via ajax. Those should probably be on the parent page (the one that makes the ajax call).

Comment: I'm not entirely certain but I believe that script tags that are inserted dynamically are loaded asynchronously. Meaning that the code below them may run *before* the script is done loading, thus the `io is undefined` error. If you move the script tags to the parent page, they'll be loaded already when the client.html page is loaded in and the code runs.